# Check continuity of functional in weak topology

Tags: functional-analysis

I have the following exercise:

Check whether the following family of seminorms is separating.

$$C[0,1]\ni f\rightarrow \sqrt{\int_0^1 |f(\frac{t}{n})|^2 dt} \in [0,\infty) \:\:\:\:\:\:\:n=1,2,3,\dots$$

If so, check continuity of functional $C[0,1]\ni f\rightarrow f(0) \in \mathbb{C}$ with respect to locally convex (weak topology) induced by this system of seminorms.

**My attempt**

I checked that indeed this family of seminorms is separating. But I don't have idea how can I check continuity. This functional is continuous in norm topology on $C[0,1]$. Doesn't it follow that it is then continuous in weak topology?

Comment: You have to check that preimages of open sets in the topology induced by those seminorms are still open in that topology.

Comment: is this topology the same as weak topology?

Comment: and open sets in that topology are unions of balls $B_{\epsilon,f_1,f_2,\dots,f_k}(x)=\{y \in X: f_i(x-y) < \epsilon \:\:\: \forall i \in \{1,\dots , k\}\}$?

Comment: The first seminorm $\|f\|$ (which is the $l^2$-norm) dominates the others (substitute $t=ns$). Continuity would thus mean that $|f(0)|\le C \|f\|$ for some constant $C$ holds for all $f\in C[0,1]$. Now try functions with large $f(0)$ but very small integral. (This is apparently the same as Lukas' comment 15 seconds ago.)

Comment: $|f(0)|\le M \cdot \|f\|_{L^2}$ ? What does it mean that the norm dominates the others?

Comment: Does it mean that $B_{\epsilon,f_1,f_2,\dots,f_k}(x)=\{y \in X: f_i(x-y) < \epsilon \:\:\: \forall i \in \{1,\dots , k\}\}=$$B_{\epsilon,f_1}(x)=\{y \in X: f_1(x-y) < \epsilon \}$ ?

Answer (score 2):

An integral of $f$ does not control pointwise behavior of $f$, because each individual point makes zero contribution to the integral. This   suggests that the functional $f\mapsto f(0)$ is **not** continuous. (Aside:   an integral  involving *derivatives* of $f$ may be able to control pointwise values of $f$, via the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.)

A counterexample is presented by functions that behave differently in a very small neighborhood of $0$ than they do elsewhere. A natural choice is $f_k=\chi_{[0,1/k]}$... except this isn't continuous, so we'd better take $f_k=\max(0,1-kx)$ instead. This sequence converges to the zero function<sup>[1]</sup> in the    topology  induced by these  seminorms, but $f_k(0)=1\not\to0$.

---

[1] Take any neighborhood of $0$. For some $r>0$ and some $N$, this neighborhood contains all functions whose $n$th seminorm is less than $r$, for $n=1,\dots,N$. Check that $f_k$ satisfies this for all sufficiently large $k$.